# What is this two-colored flower?

Tags: identification

I am concerned that thiis flower may be invasive, can someone idemtify it?

[image]

[image]

Zone is 7.

Comment: This looks like **Glebionis coronaria** in the **Asteraceae** family.

Comment: @DanD - I think you're correct: http://luirig.altervista.org/cpm/albums/bot-048/glebionis-coronaria123.jpg. You should post this as an answer.

Comment: @DanD. Right, why dont you write an answer? Why are some of these plants flower yellow-white, while others all yellow?